# getpass not working properly

Tags: python, security, python-2.7, passwords

So I don't know if I am missing some documentation, but I have two issues with `getpass`.

1. I can't seem to save the password
2. It echos the password after

   ```
   >>> pass = getpass.getpass()
     File "<stdin>", line 1
   pass = getpass.getpass()
        ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
   >>> getpass.getpass()
   Password: 
   'ryan'
   ```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass is a python keyword, meaning that you can't assign variables to it. Try `psswd` or something similar instead.

Comment: this is what you get when you mess around in terminal and don't see your sublime text keyword light up. Thanks this worked! I'll accept when I can in 3 minutes

Answer (score 0):

> 1) I can't seem to save the password.

```
>>> pass = getpass.getpass()
...
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The syntax error is expected:

```
>>> import keyword
>>> keyword.kwlist
['and', 'as', 'assert', 'break', 'class', 'continue', 'def', 'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'exec', 'finally', 'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import', 'in', 'is', 'lambda', 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'print', 'raise', 'return', 'try', 'while', 'with', 'yield']
>>> 'pass' in keyword.kwlist
True
```

You can't assign to a keyword except to those that are active only after corresponding `__future__` import.

---

> 2) It echos the password after:

```
>>> getpass.getpass()
Password: 
'most bear metal bright'
```

You see `repr()` of the returned value from `getpass()` function. Assign it to a variable:

```
>>> cleartext = getpass.getpass()
Password: 
>>> compare_hash(crypt.crypt(cleartext, hashed), hashed)
False
```